# Change default filename in SaveAs Dialog

Tags: vba, ms-word, filenames, default

I am trying to change the proposed filename within the "`Save As`"-Dialog based on the content of a Content Control.

My understanding was that Word is proposing the Document Property „`Title`“ within the `SaveAs` Dialog.

Within an empty Document I created a Content Control (Text only) and put the following code in "This Document".

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal objCC As ContentControl, _
        Cancel As Boolean)
    ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title") = objCC.Range.Text
End Sub
```

The built-in Property "`Title`" changed on leave as expected but pressing the Save As Button did not change the proposed filename.
Cancelling the "`SaveAs`"-Dialog and opening it once again (without any other actions in between) the "new" Title was proposed as default filename.

**Process:**
 1. Change Title to „New Filename“
    2. Press Save As -> Proposed Filename „Doc1“
    3. Cancel Save As
    4. Press Save As -> Proposed Filename „New Filename“
    5. Change Title to „Better Filename“
    6. Press Save As -> Proposed Filename „New Filename“
    7. Cancel Save As
    8. Press Save As -> Proposed Filename „Better Filename“

...

Is there a Workaround to this "Feature" or am I just wrong?

Comment: Which version of Word is this?

Comment: It is Word 2013.

Comment: Solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64212093/vba-set-default-save-as-name-without-opening-dialog

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood

```
Sub test()

Dim objCC As ContentControl

Set objCC = ActiveDocument.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText)

objCC.Range.Text = "Asparagus"

End Sub

Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal objCC As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title")
End Sub
```

This yields "Asparagus"

And that is also the proposed FileName on save.

Comment: The Title value  changes as soon as i assign the objCC.Range.Text to it. But the proposed filename changes only the second time a klick the Save Button.