# VBA - Set Excel Workbook Default Save As Name

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I'm having a similar problem to one I described in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64212093/vba-set-default-save-as-name-without-opening-dialog) of mine, only this time with Excel rather than Word.

I have created a spreadsheet with VBA in Access by creating a new Excel.Application then using Workbooks.Add.

I'm trying to change the suggested name that appears when a user first tries to click "Save As" in this document, but without opening the dialog immediately.

I have tried to modify the solution given to my previous problem, which solved this problem for Word. However, it seems that "xlDialogFileSummaryInfo" does not exist as a dialog, and I have been unable to find a suitable analogue.

Again, approaches such as setting

```
.ActiveWorkbook.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Title") = "My Title"
```

do not seem to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *it seems that "xlDialogFileSummaryInfo" does not exist as a dialog* Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlbuiltindialog  Maybe what you are looking for is there

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've looked through the various dialogs available and tried many out, but couldn't find one which provided similar functionality. Confusingly, there is one called "xlDialogWorkbookName", but this is actually used for renaming worksheets!

Comment: If you could intercept the Excel SaveAs call, you could replace the built-in functionality with a call to Application.GetSaveAsFilename("MyPreferredName"), and then ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(). Unfortunately the BeforeSave event is fired AFTER the SaveAs dialog is shown. You could try to change the OnAction method of the SaveAs command button ... but nowadays we have the "Backstage" ribbon, which uses XML Maybe others can suggest a way of doing that.